# JSON encode in Slim framework

Tags: twig, slim

I am having problems sending a JSON encoded array to my view.

So I am doing this in my route

```
$data['values'] = array('name'=>'John');
$data['values'] = json_encode($data['values']);
return $this->view->render($res, 'githubpresentation.html', $data);
```

And in my view, in the script tag I do this

```
var values = "{{values}}" ;
console.log(values);

values = JSON.parse(values);
console.log(values);
```

The first console.log, before the JSON.parse outputs this:

```
{&quot;name&quot;:&quot;John&quot;}
```

And when I do the JSON.parse I get an error, of course

```
Unexpected token & in JSON at position 1
```

Now I could do some sort of replace of the *&quot*, but do I really need to? Shouldn't I be able to send a JSON from the server?

Comment: Slim doesn't bundle a default template engine as far as I know. Which one are you using?

Comment: Twig. But the answer from Davide solved my problem

Comment: Because he figured out you were using Twig :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is related to the default [escaping strategy](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/filters/escape.html). You can fix it by using the js one:

```
var values = "{{values|e('js')}}" ;
console.log(values);

values = JSON.parse(values);
console.log(values);
```

Output:

```
{"name":"John"}
Object {name: "John"}
```

Comment: I have a new hero. It´s called Davide Pastore :) :)  That works man. Thx a million

Comment: I'm Batman :P Hi @PauloBorralhoMartins if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.